# Run multiple python codes and Check with answer data

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I wrote the code for my undergraduate TA jobs, to check assignment codes of students in Python class are correct or not.

Usage of the code is

```
$ python [test01.py[,test02 , ...] answer.dat grade.md
```

It will write grades (range 0~100) to a file called `grade.md`.

```
"""
Testing Assginments
by kidkkr
03-16-2017
"""

import os
import sys
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

class ResultChecker:
    """ Check python code result with answer data """
    __slots__ = '_srcFiles', '_ansFile', '_gradeFile', '_grade', '_ans'

    def __init__(self, srcFiles, ansFile, gradeFile):
        self._srcFiles = srcFiles 
        self._ansFile = ansFile 
        self._ans = open(self._ansFile, 'r').read()
        self._gradeFile = gradeFile
        self._grade = "# Grade File\n"

    def _run_code(self, src):
        print('-----------running ' + src + '..-----------')
        os.system('python ' + src + ' > result.swp')
        res = open('./result.swp', 'r').read()
        ratio = int(SequenceMatcher(None, res, self._ans).ratio() * 100)
        self._grade += src + ' ' + str(ratio) + '\n'
        print('result: ' + str(ratio))

    def check(self):
        for src in self._srcFiles:
            self._run_code(src)
        open(self._gradeFile, 'w').write(self._grade) # Write _grade to a file
        print('Checking has completed.')
        print(self._gradeFile + ":")
        print(self._grade)


def __main__():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2: # Check arguments
        raise ValueError('')

    srcFiles = sys.argv[1:-2]
    ansFile = sys.argv[-2]
    gradeFile = sys.argv[-1]

    ResultChecker(srcFiles, ansFile, gradeFile).check()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

Comment: Note that you should make sure you're being safe with untrusted scripts.  Even if they're not malicious a student could break things that could cause future tests to fail or bigger problems.  You should sandbox each run, either using something from here https://wiki.python.org/moin/Asking%20for%20Help/How%20can%20I%20run%20an%20untrusted%20Python%20script%20safely%20(i.e.%20Sandbox) or simply using a vm

Comment: I could not reached to that. It will be possible because I run codes directly in my shell.. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something I would improve:

- fix the variable naming - according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), use lower case and separate words with an underscore - e.g. `_grade_file` instead of `_gradeFile`
- use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)  module instead of manually reading from `sys.argv` - you will get the auto-generated command-line help for free and it is generally more readable, structured and scalable. As a bonus, you may avoid checking the length of the `sys.argv` and reading the "files" into variables. Something along these lines:

  ```
  import argparse


  def parse_arguments():
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

      parser.add_argument('--source-files', nargs="+", type=str)
      parser.add_argument('--answer-file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
      parser.add_argument('--grade-file', type=argparse.FileType('w'))

      return parser.parse_args()
  ```

  Note the use of the special [`FileType` argument type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type).

  And, because of the use of [`nargs="+"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15460288/771848), you should change the way you pass python file names - instead of a comma-separated list, use space:

  ```
  $ python --source-files test01.py test02.py --answer-file answer.dat --grade-file grade.md
  ```
- use [`with` context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) when opening files
- try [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead of `os.system()` - with "popen" you may not need to temporarily write the result to a swap file and read the standard out and error directly
- I understand that an underscore at the beginning of a variable name is a convention to mark ["private variables"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables), but, if the checker class would not be a part of a public-facing API, it would be okay to remove the underscores to improve on readability

Comment: `argparse` module is cool. I hope I used to PEP8.. Thank you :)